# Create NSMutableArray from Array<T> in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to write an extension where I define a new method for sorting the contained objects in-place by their property using `NSSortDescriptor`class. However, I failed to populate the mutable version of `self` for some reason and getting the following error:

```
Cannot find an initializer for type NSMutableArray that accepts an argument list of type (array: Array<T>)
```

Here is my method:

```
extension Array {

    public mutating func sortInPlace(field: String, ascending: Bool) {

        let mutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: self) // error here.

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: field, ascending: ascending)     
        mutableArray.sortUsingDescriptors([sortDescriptor])

        self = mutableArray as AnyObject as! [Generator.Element]
    }
}
```

I also tried the following but no luck:

```
let mutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: self as! [AnyObject])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your extension definition it's hard to say, but this works for me:

```
extension Array where T : AnyObject {
    func toMutableArray() -> NSMutableArray {
        return NSMutableArray(array: self)
    }
}

let array: [NSString] = ["A", "B"]
let mArray = array.toMutableArray()

print(mArray) // ( A, B )
```

The problem here is you need to constrain the extension on `Array` to only take in an array of `AnyObject`. `String` is a struct, not a class (`AnyObject` is constrained to reference types). This is also why I needed the type specifier of `[NSString]` on my array. Otherwise, it would be an array of structs, not an array of `String` values.

Comment: great! I've added a better explanation to my answer.